# Estimate angular velocity and acceleration from a sequence of rotations

Tags: quaternions

I have a set of rotations:

$R(t) \in R^{3x3}, t = 1, 2, ... T$.

I can extract the orientation of a body $\theta (t)$ from the rotation matrix $R(t)$. I am interested to estimate the angular velocity $\omega (t)$ and angular acceleration $\alpha (t)$. I have performed spline quaternion interpolation. I imagine that I can use the following formula to estimate $\omega (t)$:

$\omega = 2 \frac{dq}{dt} * \hat{q} $,

where $\hat{q}$ is the inverse of $q$. What is the formula for computing $\alpha (t)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you know the quaternion's first derivative
$$
\dot q = \frac{1}{2} \omega q
$$
which is how you got to your equation
$$
\omega = 2 \dot q \hat q
$$
The quaternion's second derivative is 
$$
\ddot q = \frac{1}{2}(\dot \omega q + \omega \dot q)
$$
and substituting the first derivative above gives
$$
\ddot q = \frac{1}{2}(\dot \omega q + \omega \frac{1}{2} \omega q)
$$
$$
\ddot q = \frac{1}{2} \dot \omega q + \frac{1}{4} \omega \omega q
$$
Which you can use to get the acceleration $\dot \omega$
$$
\dot \omega = 2 (\ddot q \hat q - (\dot q \hat q )^2)
$$

Comment: Thanks for the derivation. Regarding the quantity $(\dot{q}\hat{q})^2$ do I have to use the exponential property of quaternions?

Comment: This requires you to know $\dot{q}$ in order to find $\omega$ though. How do you get the quantity $\dot{q}$ from the sequence of quaternions?

Comment: Also, $\omega$ is 3-dimensional. You can interpret it as a quaternion with 0 scalar part, but how do you enforce that it gets 0 scalar part when you compute it in this way as the scaled product of two quaternions?

Comment: I estimated $\dot{q}, \ddot{q}$ by fitting quaternion splines and evaluating the derivatives.