# Derivation for angular acceleration from quaternion profile

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, quaternions

Given a profile of unit quaternions $q(t)$ that represents the orientation of a body over time, I like to get the angular acceleration $\dot \omega (t)$.
I tried to find a formula myself, but I get two different results for two different derivations.

**Derivation 1**

Starting from the kinematic equations

$$\omega=2\dot{q}\hat{q}$$

$$\dot{\omega}=2(\ddot{q}\hat{q}+\dot q \hat{\dot{q}})$$

And using the property of conjugate quaternions:

$$\dot\omega=2\ddot q \hat q$$

**Derivation 2**

Again, taking the kinematic equation

$$\dot q = \frac 1 2 \omega q$$

But now taking the derivative of $q$ w.r.t. $t$ gives

$$ \ddot q=\frac 1 2 (\dot \omega q+\omega\dot q) $$

After substituting the formula for $\omega$

$$ \ddot q=\frac{1}{2} (\dot \omega q+2 \dot q\hat q \dot q)$$

Finally, the result after multiplying both sided by $\hat q$ and rearranging is

$$\dot \omega  = 2\ddot q\hat q -2(\dot q \hat q)^2$$

Which of these derivations is correct, and why?
I have already consulted several sources, where I seem to find both formulas. 
For example [here](http://bicycle.tudelft.nl/schwab/Publications/quaternion.pdf) for derivation 1 and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1792826/estimate-angular-velocity-and-acceleration-from-a-sequence-of-rotations) for derivation 2. I'm new to using quaternions, so maybe I'm missing some mathematical concept.

Comment: I think this question would be much more appropriate for Physics Stack Exchange.

Comment: Thanks, I will do. However, I found more useful related posts on Mathematics stack exchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not a physicist but, to my understanding, both derivations are equal.

In your first derivation you get:

$\dot\omega = 2\ddot q \hat q + 2 \dot q \hat{\dot q} $

In your second derivation you get the same. Departing from the unit quaternion condition:

$q \hat q = 1$

$0 = \frac{d}{dt}(q \hat q) = \dot q \hat q  + q \hat{\dot q}$

We get the identity:

$\dot q \hat q  = - q \hat{\dot q}$

So the square $(\dot q\hat q)^2 = - \dot q \hat{\dot q}$ because:

$(\dot q\hat q)^2 = \dot q\hat q (\dot q \hat q) =  -\dot q \hat q q \hat{\dot q}  = - \dot q \hat{\dot q}$

And you get again:

$\dot\omega = 2\ddot q \hat q + 2 \dot q \hat{\dot q} $